# How to deal with high resolution devices while porting for android?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently developed a car parking game using Unity 2018, and I was facing a lot of stutters on my Note 4. Later I turned down the device resolution to 1080p from 1440, and the stuttering was gone. I would like to know how can I detect if a device resolution is above 1080p and downscale it or if there is another better way of handling it, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Screen.SetResolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) to set a specific value (do it in `Awake()` on some script in your first scene) and then make sure you adjust the [Blit Type](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidBlitType.html) in Player Settings to `Always` or you'll run into [this problem](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1494067/screensetresolution-does-not-cover-all-screen.html).